# Adding common values in a file awk memory efficient solution

Tags: awk

I have a file containing value and frequency. I used the following command awk {a[$1]+=$2} END 
 to add the frequency of the columns with same value. However the file contains 3gb of data , and i need a memory efficient solution. So I sorted the file first and tried adding consecutive columns if they are same, but I am failing to do so,

Comment: can you post a short sample sorted input file and the awk command you tried for that... plus the expected sample output...

Comment: I think splitting the file would help too..

Comment: The fact that your input file is 3g is irrelevant, what matters is how many unique `value`s you have. So - about how many can you have? If the answer is 5 then the required solution will be very different from if the answer is 3g. As requested already, post concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. I see you sorted the file first - sort reads the whole file into memory to do it's job so how was that memory efficient? Maybe you're trying to solve a problem you don't have.

Answer (score 1):

How about if you sort the data first and process after:

```
$ cat > assumed_data.txt
VALUE1 1
VALUE2 2
VALUE1 3
VALUE2 4
$ sort assumed_data.txt|awk 'NR>1 && prev != $1 {print prev, sum; sum=0} {sum+=$2; prev=$1} END {print prev, sum}'
VALUE1 4
VALUE2 6
```

Comment: While a reasonable approach, if the OP doesn't have enough memory for `awk` to read in the whole file then he almost certainly doesn't have enough memory for `sort` to read in the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

... or count and print them out in batches, for example process 1000 lines and print them out to another file, then the next 1000 lines and append to the same file:

```
$ cat divisum.awk
NR % 1000 ==0 {
    for(i in sum) 
        print i, sum[i]
    delete sum
} 
{
    sum[$1]+=$2
} 
END {
    for(i in sum) 
        print i, sum[i]
}
$ awk -f divisum.awk assumed_data.txt > summedsome.txt
```

and then:

```
$ awk -f divisum.awk summedsome.txt > summedsomore.txt
```

... and so on. Not knowing your data at all 1000 may or may not be a good number of lines. If your file has exactly 1000 different values spread evenly, 1000 lines at a time is not going to solve your problem.

Comment: You'd have to add some external logic to loop until the output file has all unique values which would mean you'd need something like an array of values to track what's been seen and increment the count of unique values when a new value is seen which means you're back to having an array of unique values which is the problem the OP claims he has to solve - that he doesn't have enough memory for an array of unique values.

Answer (score 0):

IF you really have a memory problem, which I'm not convinced you do since you could run `sort` on your file, then you'd need something like this to address it:

```
awk '
    !full {
        if ( ($1 > prevMax) || (NR == FNR) ) {
            sum[$1] += $2
            if ( length(sum) == 1000000 ) {
                full = 1
                for ( i in sum ) {
                    min = ( $1<min ? $1 : min)
                    max = ( $1>max ? $1 : max)
                }
            }
        }
        next
    }
    ($1 >= min) && ($1 =< max) {
        sum[$1] += $2
    }
    ENDFILE {
        if ( length(sum) > 0 ) {
            for ( i in sum ) {
                print i, sum[i]
            }
            ARGV[ARGC] = FILENAME
            ARGC++
            delete sum
            full = 0
            prevMax = max
        }
    }
' file
```

Check the math/logic but hopefully you get the idea that you count up to 1000000 unique values at a time and just keep adding the input file back onto the ARGV list until there's no more unique values. Massage the 1000000 to suit.

The above uses GNU awk for ENDFILE, with other awks you'd have to use a count of number of lines in the file or use FNR==1 with an exit or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can often trade RAM for disk, so make one pass through the file splitting it into files by value - so all `VALUE1` frequencies go in file `f.VALUE1`, and all `VALUE2` frequencies go in file `f.VALUE2`.

```
awk '{print $2 > "f." $1}' yourFile
```

Then you trivially need to total the numbers in each of `f.*`. This solution holds no more than one line in memory at a time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of approaching this is with **GNU Parallel**. It can chunk up the file into blocks of arbitrary sizes and process them in parallel for you. It will only split on full lines - unless you do other stuff which I am not suggesting, so there is no risk of splitting within a line.

So, assuming I use your `awk` script in `script.awk` as follows:

```
{a[$1]+=$2}
END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}
```

and assuming your file is called `data`, I can have **GNU Parallel** chunk your file into 10MB lumps and pass them to as many `awk`s in parallel as your CPU has cores:

```
parallel -a data --pipepart --block 10m awk -f ./script.awk
```

Now that will reduce your data as long as there are some repeated values in any 10MB chunk. You can obviously make the chunk larger and it will make a bigger reduction, as you will have better locality of reference, and you can also test your theory that you are short of memory by varying the chunk size. You can also apply the above repeatedly till the file size is less than the memory which means you got it all in memory one go. I mean:

```
parallel -a data  --pipepart --block 10m awk -f ./script.awk > part1
parallel -a part1 --pipepart --block 10m awk -f ./script.awk > part2
```

As Ed says, the question is how many *unique* values you have, not how many values you have. The fewer unique values you have, and the closer they are together in the file, the faster this method will converge.